# Opposite of display:none in a td

Tags: javascript, html

I have a td that has a class which has a css rule to display:none. When I add this class to the td, it disappears, and when I remove the class, it reappears.

However, if the td is display:none, I can't come up with a way of overriding display to show it like normal. I tried values: block, inline, '', inherit, and table. None of them worked, all displaying them in odd ways. Surely there must be some way to override the display rule on a td to act like I described above.

Comment: Are you trying to make it visible by using Javascript or CSS?

Comment: trying to make it visible using css

Comment: A warning: in old versions of IE (before 8), if cells in a table are not visible at the time the table is first shown, then it may be the case that you'll never be able to make them show up.  That's not always true, but it's definitely true sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Just set display to empty, or display: table-cell

Comment: I'm trying to do this with css and setting it to empty doesn't appear to work. Also, display: table-cell is not ie6 compatible

Answer (score 0):

You have a table cell. Try `display:table-cell`.

Comment: I believe this is not IE6 compatible

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decipher exactly what you mean by "trying to do this with css".  It sounds like you have two classes

```
.hideMe {
  display: none;
}
.showMe {
  display: block;
}
```

and you're applying both classes to an element such as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td class="hideMe showMe">Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  ....
```

That will not work -- Though I'm not sure why.

I would recommend just having one class for hiding (e.g. "display: none;") and add/remove that class as needed to show or hide the elements.