# Turn off display: none in CSS for a TD

Tags: javascript, html

I have a css file that looks like:

```
td { display: none; }
.showCell { display: ???? }
```

I have a td that I want to draw on the screen theoretically by giving it the class "showCell". However, I don't know what value for ????? would make this work on all browsers. The value table-cell works on all but ie6 and 7.

Note: this is similar to the question I just asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696210/opposite-of-displaynone-in-a-td). But I asked it poorly there and so please close it if you can.

Comment: Can't you just turn off display: none?

Comment: no, this is a simplified version of what is really going on, and I must do it in css for efficiency reasons

Comment: really without a little more detail about why it doesn't work we can't help you. For instance, it could be the specificity of the td versus the .showCell. There's lots of reasons why it might not work. All I can say is build us an exact test case with as few parts as possible that shows what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In Internet Explorer 7 and earlier, the default value of [the display] property for table, tr, td, col, and colGroup elements is block."

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The easiest way to achieve this would be via conditional comments. Just put it in a special stylesheet for IE6 and IE7

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6and7fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

which would then have

```
.showCell {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
.showCell { display: table-cell }
```

Comment: display: table-cell doesn't work in IE6 and IE7. That was my first instinct, too, but Joda said it didn't work. display: block makes absolutely no sense since you'd expect it to cause each cell to be forced down vertically, but, unfortunately, that's what Microsoft went with.

Answer (score 2):

For a table cell you need

```
display: table-cell
```

Comment: The OP's question says that `table-cell` doesn't work for IE6 and IE7

Answer (score 1):

Try this: .showCell { display: table-cell !IMPORTANT }

Answer (score 0):

You could try `display: block;`. This might mess up the layout of your table, but older IEs dont support table-cell, so you don't really have too much to choose from.